# MS Access only showing one result

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm working on a MS Access application but have encountered an issue.
I've tried searching around, however, haven't had any luck so I've come here!

I created a multiple items form and have a search button which activates the query it's linked to. This all works fine and all the right information is returned, however, only one record displays at a time.

Say there are 5 results I have to use the record selector to scroll through them each individually despite there being heaps of room left on the form.

None of my other multiple item forms do this.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Always the way - post on here and finally work it out.

The answer was to change it to a continuous form if anyone else ever has this issue!